# matrix calculus (differentiation of complex matrix)

Tags: calculus

I know that $f(x)=||Ax-b||_2^2$ (real matrix) has gradient $\partial f/\partial x=A^T(Ax-b)$.

Now suppose $A$ is complex, then how can I prove that $\partial f/\partial x=A^*(Ax-b)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $x$ is real in both cases. For real-valued $A$ and $b$ you have

$$f(x)=||Ax-b||_2^2=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)=x^TA^TAx-2x^TA^Tb+b^Tb$$

So

$$\partial f/\partial x=2A^T(Ax-b)$$

For complex $A$ and $b$ we get

$$f(x)=||Ax-b||_2^2=(Ax-b)^H(Ax-b)=x^TA^HAx-x^TA^Hb-b^HAx+b^Hb=\\
=x^TA^HAx-2x^T\text{Re}\{A^Hb\}+b^Hb$$

where $^H$ denotes hermitian conjugation.

The derivative w.r.t. $x$ is then

$$\partial f/\partial x=2(A^HAx-\text{Re}\{A^Hb\})$$

Comment: What would happen if $x$ is a complex vector?